# TODO Explorer - Incorrect entries for Note

Tags: visual-studio-2010, resharper

What would be a good workaround for [this](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/RSRP-149984) issue, where the resharper TODO explorer lists a lot of false "Note" elements in resx files because of these lines: *"Note - application/x-microsoft.net.object.binary.base64 is the format"*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ilya Ryzhenkov from Jetbrains has just responded to your issue:

> You can change or disable patterns in ReSharper Options. E.g. change it to match "Note:"

Comment: Wow, after a year of inactivity, that was fast. Thank you stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

It took me a while to figure out the regex to make it happen, but I finally found the right way to do this.

```
^(?!.*application/x\-microsoft\.net\.object\.binary\.base64)(\W|^)(?<TAG>NOTE)(\W|$)(.*)
```

Now you don't have to use special forms of "Note" to avoid the error.  The first bit of the regex is a forward negative look ahead, saying basically that if the line contains `application/x-microsoft.net.object.binary.base64` anywhere in it, then it doesn't count.